# adding ratings to the google places using it's API for a particular place / entity

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

We are developing a Customer feedback application and I would like to push the ratings the customer given for a particular hotels or other business in to Google places. But the API designed to select the ratings only. Is there anyway I can add ratings / comments for a particular place using API?

Comment: What API are designed to select the ratings only?

Comment: If you believe this would be a useful feature you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, the Places API does not allow you to add ratings to a particular place.